# Cómo puedo agregar elementos <li> a un <ul> desde una función Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

Les cuento, tengo esta función **javascript** que agrega un li a un ul desde Javascript

```
function addUserOnline(avatar, nombre) {
    var contenido = '';
    contenido += '<li class="list-group-item clearfix">';
    contenido += ' <a href="#">';
    contenido += '<img src="' + avatar + '" alt="avatar" class="avatar">';
    contenido += '<span class="name">' + nombre + '</span>';
    contenido += ' </a>';
    contenido += '</li>';
    $('#onlineusers').append(contenido);
}
```

Estoy utilizando **Signalr** porque quiero que cada que un usuario ingrese a la aplicación lo agregue en un li a la lista ul en tiempo real.

En el evento hub.start llamo dos funciones

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {    
    alert(usuario);    
    addUserOnline(imagen, usuario);    
});
```

la función alert se ejecuta correctamente pero la otra no agrega el nuevo elemento li a la lista ul....
los valores de imagen y usuario los obtengo al inicio del archivo javascript.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: La función es correcta. Basta con copiar el código en jsfiddle para comprobarlo. ¿algo que se vea en la consola?

Comment: la función tal como indica @MitsuG se ve correcta, verifica que el  ` ul ` tenga el mismo nombre y no estés encontrando el control, ya que esta podría ser una causa

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el `HTML` del `ul` al que quieres agregar los `li`?

Answer (score 1):

Que tal, tu función esta bien pero creo que deberías hacerle un `refresh` al `listview` que estas utilizando.

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
function addUserOnline(avatar, nombre) {
    var contenido = '';
    contenido += '<li class="list-group-item clearfix">';
    contenido += ' <a href="#">';
    contenido += '<img src="' + avatar + '" alt="avatar" class="avatar">';
    contenido += '<span class="name">' + nombre + '</span>';
    contenido += ' </a>';
    contenido += '</li>';
    $('#onlineusers').append(contenido);
    $("#onlineusers").listview("refresh");
}
```

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es hacerle un `trigger("create")`
En lugar del `listview("refresh")`

Prueba y comenta si te funciona.

Comment: ¿Esto es una prueba al azar para ver si funciona? ¿O es una respuesta a la pregunta que soluciona el problema?

Comment: Funciona perfecto, Gracias hermano!